# Symfony how to hide login form if authenticated

Tags: authentication, symfony, router

If user is authenticated but somehow lands on (goes back to) the /login route, the login form is displayed, making it appear as though user is in fact not logged in.

How can I redirect from that? I tried this below...

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        
        if ($this->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') || $this->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
            
            $user = $this->getUser();
            $startpage = $user->getStartpage();

            if ( $startpage ) {
                $targetUrl = $this->router->generate($startpage);
            } else {
                $targetUrl = $this->router->generate('user_dashboard');
            }

            return $this->redirect($targetUrl);
            //return new RedirectResponse($targetUrl);

        }
        
        return $this->render('security/login_microsoft.html.twig', [
            'error' => $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError(),
            'last_username' => $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername(),
        ]);            
    

    }
```

... but I get this error:

> Warning: Undefined property:
> App\Controller\SecurityController::$router

Comment: In your *security.yaml*, you can set `default_target_path: your_admin_controller_name` under [form_login](https://symfony.com/doc/7.0/security.html#form-login). If the user goes to the login page and is already authenticated, they should be directed to your secured area.

Comment: Here is the reference to [default_target_path](https://symfony.com/doc/5.2/security/form_login.html#redirecting-after-success). It is from older docs (5.2) but is still relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to fix your error:

```php
if ( $startpage ) {
    $targetUrl = $this->get('router')->generate($startpage);
} else {
    $targetUrl = $this->get('router')->generate('user_dashboard');
}
```

You can also inject the router service in your Controller and get rid of AbstractController by adding this inside your Controller:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

public function __construct(
    private UrlGeneratorInterface $router,
) {
}
```